# Ability to Take or Select Photo from Gallery in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin-forms-4

Is there a way in Xamarin.Forms iOS to take photo or select image from Gallery?

Same functionality when you open a camera in the device. It will give you ability to take a photo or open gallery.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, we recommend using [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios),just as Jason mentioned.

The `MediaPicker` class let us pick or take a photo or video on the device.

To start using this API, read the [getting started guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Cios) for Xamarin.Essentials to ensure the library is properly installed and set up in your projects.

And to access the MediaPicker functionality the following platform specific setup is required.

```
In IOS, add the following keys in your `Info.plist`:

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to microphone for taking videos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery for picking photos and videos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos gallery for picking photos and videos.</string>
```

Note:Ensure that you update the `<string>` in each to a description specific for your app as it will be shown to your users.

And the `MediaPicker` class has the following methods that all return a `FileResult` that can be used to get the files location or read it as a Stream.

- **PickPhotoAsync**: Opens the media browser to select a photo.
- **CapturePhotoAsync**: Opens the camera to take a photo.
- **PickVideoAsync**: Opens the media browser to select a video.
- **CaptureVideoAsync**: Opens the camera to take a video.

For more, you can check document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios .